# Using Like T SQL Statement to search and replace quotation marks

Tags: sql-server

Because the quotation mark is a special character is there a way to replace all quotation with nothing

Original Query

```
Update table X
Set mycolumn = Replace(mycolumn,''','')
Where mycolumn like '%'%'
```

Error

> (Incorrect SQL Syntax - Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `'` by doubling it:

```
Update table X
Set mycolumn = Replace(mycolumn,'''','')
Where mycolumn like '%''%'
```

Though the `Where` clause is probably redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the single quote `'` by doubling `''`

```
Update table X 
Set mycolumn = Replace(mycolumn,'''','')
```

you don't need the superfluous WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - not entirely sure what you are up to, but you could try the [QuoteName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) string function.